Is it forbidden to speak ill of the dying?
It’s clear mdrabbanan that one shouldn’t speak ill of the dead but what about some in the process. Not known if he is a goses

Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Than you for your first question.  To comply with rules of the cite, could you be specific in your question? Could you also add for the Miderabannan reference? Thank you.

I was under the impression that it is forbidden to speak ill.

What if you are saying publicly known information?
